# Track custom impressions in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytic's Enhanced Ecommerce Plugin has product impressions that track views of shown products. I have products AND multiple businesses in my search result, therefore, I want to track business impressions. Everything I found so far is based on events, but I'm unsure if events are the right way to track such search impressions.

One major drawback that I see is, I send the events on page load, and not after some interaction has happended from the user. Tracking events like this

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Business',
  eventAction: 'impression',
  eventLabel: 'Supermarket 123',
  nonInteraction: true
});
```

results in an additional call to `https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect`. I think that's a waste of bandwith (especially on mobile=, because it could be send along with the `pageview`.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to send events along with the pageview?
2. Is there another / better way to track something like search impressions for non-products?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the bandwidth even on mobile shouldn't be a problem except you audience lives on the countryside of 3rd world countries (*).
Now to your questions:

1) No, you can't send everything in one hit.

2) If you think EE isn't the best fit solution you can always use regular event and product level custom dimensions. But i would like to insist that in most cases even when your 'products' are not the standard easy to track clothe like products, you can take advantage of the fields provided by EE and generate your own schema using this fields. ProTip: The category is 5 fields in one cause of the '/' separator.

(*)If this is really a problem you should look into making the requests Async and personally i would recommend **GTM**.

Hope it helps.